# How to change styles of several child divs of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a navigation and I don't want to use CSS3 to make gradient background instead of that i use images. But buttons has corners so my button is made from 3 images to make its size proportional to text. I am trying to change background on hover and I need to change all 3 backgrounds: left, right and mid. I tried jquery but it doesn't seem to work..

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.topnavbtn').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).$('.left').css('background','url(images/nav/images/navLeft_on.png) no-repeat');
        $(this).$('.mid').css('background','url(images/nav/images/navBg_on.png) no-repeat');
        $(this).$('.right').css('background','url(images/nav/images/navRight_on.png) no-repeat');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).$('.left').css('background','url(images/nav/images/navLeft.png) no-repeat');
        $(this).$('.mid').css('background','url(images/nav/images/navBg.png) no-repeat');
        $(this).$('.right').css('background','url(images/nav/images/navRight.png) no-repeat');
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none; margin:0; padding:0;padding:10px;">
<li>
<a href="#">
<div class="topnavbtn">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="mid">asdassdfdssdfsd</div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">
<div class="topnavbtn">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="mid">asdassdfdssdfsd</div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">
<div class="topnavbtn">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="mid">asdassdfdssdfsd</div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</a>
</li>

</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
.topnavbtn {
    height:34px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:7px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#FFF;
    line-height: 34px;
}

.topnavbtn .left {
    height:34px;
    width:9px;
    background:url(images/nav/images/navLeft.png) no-repeat;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}

.topnavbtn .right {
    height:34px;
    width:9px;
    background:url(images/nav/images/navRight.png) no-repeat;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}

.topnavbtn .mid {
    background:url(images/nav/images/navBg.png) repeat-x;
    height:34px;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: why wouldn't you want to use CSS3 instead of 3 images? also http://learn.jquery.com

Comment: I agree I use CSS3 for my styled buttons it is so much easier I must say. I have tried both options, the jquery and css3 options, and the css3 is much cleaner.

Comment: I want it to work on IE. And also learn jquery a bit because I think it's really useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a syntax error :

```
$(this).$('.left').css(...
```

try

```
$('.left', this).css(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
$(this).$('.left')
```

with

```
$(this).children('.left')
```

and so on for rest of classes .